# Unmerge cells only for rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have four cells merged together: two columns and two rows. I need to get only the columns merged together with separate rows (there fore get 2 cells in the end).

How would I do it in vba? I know of `.MergeCells = False` option but it looks like splitting all the cells apart.

Comment: I don't think it have a shortcut for that.  You need to unmerge it, and merge by row again.

Comment: @Prisoner, How would I merge by row?

Comment: @Ans select the cells in a row you want to merge. Next to "Merge and Centre" there is a small down arrow. Click it, and click "Merge Across".

Comment: [Doc: Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840729.aspx), You may specific the `Across` as it stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following vba macro merges a given area into individual merged rows.
So a merged 2x2 area like this:

```
┌    ─    ┐
  A1   B1
│         │
  A2   B2
└    ─    ┘
```

will become merged into individual rows:

```
┌    ─    ┐
  A1   B1
├    ─    ┤
  A2   B2
└    ─    ┘
```

The macro is called like this:

```
MergedAreaToRows rngMergedArea:=Range("A1:B2")
```

It is quite generic, so it can merge every combination of rows and columns into individual rows.

```
Sub MergedAreaToRows(ByRef rngMergedArea As Range)

    'do it only if area consists of more than a cell
    If rngMergedArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then

        'unmerge area
        rngMergedArea.UnMerge

        'only if more than one column -> need to merge again
        If rngMergedArea.Columns.Count > 1 Then

            'iterate through rows
            Dim intRow As Integer
            For intRow = 1 To rngMergedArea.Rows.Count

                'merge area by rows again
                rngMergedArea.Rows(intRow).Merge

            Next intRow

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Prisoner suggested

Assuming the four merged cells are the following:

```
A1    B1
A2    B2
```

Your code becomes:

```
Range("A1:B2").MergeCells = False
Range("A1:B1").MergeCells = True
Range("A2:B2").MergeCells = True
```